# Detect item view on Adapter has been destroyed

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I have a ListView with a BaseAdapter. I want to update some items on the list very often without refreshing the content. In order to achieve this I'm using the Observer pattern. I have an Observable object and every item in the list is an observer.

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ItemViewHolder holder;
        final Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

            /* ADD VIEWS TO HOLDER */

            holder = new ItemViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            ItemObserver observer = new ItemObserver(holder, context);
            mapObservers.put(holder, observer);
            observable.addObserver(observer);
        } else {
            holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Set values into view etc...
        return convertView;
    }
```

This works well but the issue is: how do I know the observer is not longer needed?. I want to detect when a given view is destroyed in order to get the observer from the Map and delete it from the Observable object. Is there any listener that is called when the view is destroyed?

I tried `AbsListView.RecyclerListener.onMovedToScrapHeap(View view)` but it seems to be called when the View is recycled.

Thank you!

Comment: Late to the party but may help somebody. `onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: RepositoryViewHolder)` in adapter does what the question is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this offical issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5708), There is an issue with the `onViewDetachFromWindow` BUT

> onDetachedFromWindow() will not necessarily be called in this
> situation. ListView
> children are recycled and reused, and ListView avoids unnecessary
> onDetachedFromWindow() whenever possible.
> However, onDetachedFromWindow()
> should be called for all views created by the adapter when the Activity is destroyed or
> when ListView is detached from the window.

So you can't expect the listview views to be destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Your item view must extend android View and override next method:

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    // View is now detached, and about to be destroyed.
    // Remove observer here.
}
```

## EDIT

After reading the comments, I decided to explain a little bit how the list view works.

The biggest problem is that the views are being reused by the adapter. When you scroll down the list, the most upper item view is reused (not destroyed!) to show the most lower item view. This is reflected in next method if you override the getView() method of the adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ...
    return view;
}
```

What it does behind:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
       view = convertView;
    }
```

So, the convertView is never destroyed, but **reused**. Getting back to the problem, you just should update holder values depending on variable *position*, after the line:

```
    holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    // Update your holder/observer here. Something like:
    holder.setPosition(position);
```

Comment: same issue. I tried override onDetachedFromWindow, but it's never been called when I scroll up and down.

Comment: I mean item view should extend android View, not ListView.